# Google.Apis.Analytics.v3 stops working on July 1 2023?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I have an code implementation to read data from UA.

```
private readonly AnalyticsService service;
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;
        private ILogger<PageViewService> _logger;

public PageViewService(IConfiguration config, ILogger<PageViewService> logger)
        {
            try
            {
                _config = config;
                _logger = logger;

                var sercretFileLocation = _config["SecretFileLocation"];
                var password = _config["Password"];
                var accountEmail = _config["AccountEmail"];
    
                X509KeyStorageFlags storageFlag = X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet;
                var flag = _config["X509KeyStorageFlags"];
                if (flag == "UserKeySet")
                {
                    storageFlag = X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet;
                }
                else if (flag == "MachineKeySet")
                {
                    storageFlag = X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet;
                }
                else if (flag == "Exportable")
                {
                    storageFlag = X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable;

                }
                else if (flag == "UserProtected")
                {
                    storageFlag = X509KeyStorageFlags.UserProtected;

                }
                else if (flag == "PersistKeySet")
                {
                    storageFlag = X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet;
                }
                else if (flag == "EphemeralKeySet")
                {
                    storageFlag = X509KeyStorageFlags.EphemeralKeySet;
                }
                else if (flag == "DefaultKeySet")
                {
                    storageFlag = X509KeyStorageFlags.DefaultKeySet;
                }

                var certificate = new X509Certificate2(sercretFileLocation, password, storageFlag);
                var scopes = new string[] { AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly };

                var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(accountEmail)
                {
                    Scopes = scopes
                }.FromCertificate(certificate));


                service = new AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential
                });
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.LogError(e.ToString());
            }
        }

 public string GetPageViews(List<string> paths)
        {
            string pathsString = "";
            try
            {
                var webSiteCode = _config["WebSiteCode"];
                var startDate = _config["StartDate"];

                if (webSiteCode != null && startDate != null)
                {
                    pathsString = GenerateFilter(paths);

                    DataResource.GaResource.GetRequest request = service.Data.Ga.Get(
                       "ga:" + webSiteCode,
                      startDate,
                       "today",
                       "ga:uniquePageviews");
                    request.Filters = pathsString;

                    var data = request.Execute();
                    string uniquePageViews = data?.Rows?.FirstOrDefault()?.FirstOrDefault();
                    return uniquePageViews;
                }
                else
                {
                    return "0";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"{e.ToString()} {pathsString}");
            }
            return null; //null means there is an error.
        }
```

Direct to the point questions:

1. Will the code above stops working on July 2023?
2. I already connected my UA to GA4 using GA4 Setup Assistant on April 2022 . and my GA4 already started retrieving metrics starting April 2022. Is connecting my UA to GA4 using GA4 Setup assistant still work with the above code?
3. Do I have to change my code to use Google.Apis.AnalyticsReporting.v4? If I use that package, is using the View ID of my UA still works on July 2023?

I tried to create this prototype but this still requires View ID. GA4 does not have View ID so I used the View ID from my UA. As mentioned my UA is connected to my GA4, will this implementation still works on July 2023? Do I have to switch to this implementation on July 2023?

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            var dateRange = new DateRange

            {

                StartDate = "2020-06-01",

                EndDate = "2020-06-30"

            };

            var dimensions = new List<Dimension>

         {

            new Dimension { Name = "ga:pagePath" },

            new Dimension { Name = "ga:pageTitle" }

         };


            var metrics = new List<Metric>

         {

            new Metric { Expression = "ga:pageViews" },

            new Metric { Expression = "ga:users" }

         };


            var reportRequest = new ReportRequest

            {

                DateRanges = new List<DateRange> { dateRange }, 
                Dimensions = dimensions,

                Metrics = metrics,

                FiltersExpression = filtersExpression,

                ViewId = "ga:12345678" 
            };

            var getReportsRequest = new GetReportsRequest

            {

                ReportRequests = new List<ReportRequest> { reportRequest }

            };


            var credential = GetGoogleCredential("C:\\Code\\PrototypeAnalytics4\\PrototypeAnalytics4\\mychuva.json");



            // Create an AnalyticsReportingService object to make the Google Analytics API call
            var analyticsService = new AnalyticsReportingService(new BaseClientService.Initializer

            {

                ApplicationName = "chuva-123",
                HttpClientInitializer = credential 
            });

 
            var batchGetRequest = analyticsService.Reports.BatchGet(getReportsRequest);
            var getReportsResponse = await batchGetRequest.ExecuteAsync();
            var analyticsData = getReportsResponse.Reports[0].Data;

        }


        static GoogleCredential GetGoogleCredential(string pathGAKey)

        {

            GoogleCredential credential;

            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(pathGAKey, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))

            {

                credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream); 
            }


            string[] scopes = new string[]

            {

            AnalyticsReportingService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly

            };



            credential = credential.CreateScoped(scopes); 


            return credential;
        }
```

Comment: you need to use the Google Analytics data api.